# Phenotypic Variation of cattle - looking for academic sources

Tags: genetics

Can someone please point me in the direction of a good academic article on the following:

What are possible sources of phenotypic variation of different 400 day weights of cattle?

Furthermore how much variation is likely to be due to each contributing source?

I have tried the following searches in google scholar:

- Phenotypic, genetic, environmental cattle weight
- Phenotypic variation cattle weight
- Phenotypic variation
- Phenotypic variation, genetic
- genetic variation, dam, sire

Comment: this is a subject that has been well understood by cattle breeders but is not an academic research topic I think.  This is not my field, but this article might point you in the right direction http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2012/05/the-perfect-milk-machine-how-big-data-transformed-the-dairy-industry/256423/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Online Mendelian Inheritance in Animals (OMIA)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/omia) is a database of genes, inherited disorders and traits in more than 135 animal species (other than human and mouse). At the moment, it has [about 400 entries for *Bos taurus*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/omia?term=bos), mostly disease phenotypes. This is probably the only attempt to exhaustively list such phenotypes.